ojdbc11 23.3.0.23.09 or above not working against gvenzl/oracle-xe on Apple M3
I have a https://hub.docker.com/r/gvenzl/oracle-xe container running with help of https://github.com/abiosoft/colima on Apple M3 Max.
I have a server running Azul JVM 21 and the highest version of https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.oracle.database.jdbc/ojdbc11 that I can run is 23.2.0.0. All other versions above from 23.3.0.23.09 up to 23.5.0.24.07 result in the runtime error:
Aug 20, 2024 10:29:01 AM oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection connect
INFO: entering args (oracle.jdbc.internal.AbstractConnectionBuilder$1@2532b351)
Aug 20, 2024 10:29:01 AM oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol connect
INFO: traceId=7CEDFA63. 
Aug 20, 2024 10:29:01 AM oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol establishConnection
INFO: Session Attributes: 
sdu=8192, tdu=2097152
nt: host=localhost, port=1521, socketOptions={0=YES, 1=NO, 17=0, 18=false, 2=30000, 20=true, 38=TLS, 23=40, 24=50, 40=false, 25=0}
    socket=null
client profile={oracle.net.encryption_types_client=(), oracle.net.crypto_seed=, oracle.net.authentication_services=(), oracle.net.setFIPSMode=false, oracle.net.kerberos5_mutual_authentication=false, oracle.net.encryption_client=ACCEPTED, oracle.net.crypto_checksum_client=ACCEPTED, oracle.net.crypto_checksum_types_client=()}
onBreakReset=false, dataEOF=true, negotiatedOptions=0x0, connected=false
TTIINIT enabled=false, TTC cookie enabled=false

Aug 20, 2024 10:29:01 AM oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol configureSessionAttsAno
INFO: traceId=7CEDFA63, anoEnabled=true. 
Aug 20, 2024 10:29:01 AM oracle.net.ns.NSProtocolNIO handleConnectPacketResponse
INFO: Got Refused, SessionTraceId = 7CEDFA63
Aug 20, 2024 10:29:01 AM oracle.net.ns.NSProtocolNIO establishConnectionAfterRefusePacket
INFO: Outbound interrupt timer cancelled null
Aug 20, 2024 10:29:01 AM oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection connect
INFO: throwing
java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: ORA-18958: Invalid refuse packet data. (CONNECTION_ID=xB3e5AK6Tl++nc2vCpPGXQ==)
https://docs.oracle.com/error-help/db/ora-18958/
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.handleLogonNetException(T4CConnection.java:1617)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:1139)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.connect(PhysicalConnection.java:1206)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:105)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:886)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:693)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:138)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:364)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:206)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:476)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:561)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:115)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.<init>(HikariDataSource.java:81)

